# Why in hibernate sql is there despite of HQL

Tags: hibernate

In Hibernate  why we are using native SQL  despite HQL query is there,we can do everything by hql .

Comment: HQL is limited, HQL generates SQL, so two operations in one can reduce the overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch18.html) says:

> This is useful if you want to utilize database-specific features such
>   as query hints or the CONNECT keyword in Oracle. It also provides a
>   clean migration path from a direct SQL/JDBC based application to
>   Hibernate.

It also seems that you actually [can *not* do anything with HQL alone](http://hedleyproctor.com/2014/08/hibernate-query-limitations-and-correlated-sub-queries/) (unverified by me, so if in doubt I'd stick with the explanation from the documentation):

> It’s well known that one of the key limitations of writing queries in
>   Hibernate, using either HQL or criteria, is that you cannot write
>   queries that have a join in the from clause.

Answer (score 0):

A Simple example (often quoted too...) is if you want to use feature like HINT in your query so that Oracle picks up the Desired Execution Path. This we will not be able to do in the current versions of HQL.